# Calculating expectation by change of probability measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $B^a_t$ and $B^b_t$ for any $t\in[0,T]$ where $T>0$ be Brownian motions under probability measure $P$ with correlation $\rho\geq 0$.

The task is to calculate
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(B^a_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{E}$ is the operator for stochastic exponential. Note that $\mathcal{E}(B^i_t)=\exp(-t/2+B_t^i)$ which is a $P$-martingale for any $i\in\{a,b\}$. Let $f$ be the density function of the standard normal distribution.

Approach 1: Define an equivalent probability measure $Q$ by $\frac{dQ}{dP}=\mathcal{E}(B^a_T)$, then by Girsanov's theorem $\tilde{B}^b_t:=B^b_t-\rho t$ is a Brownian motion under $Q$ and by $\tilde{B}^b_T\sim \mathcal{N}(0,T)$ it follows that
$$\begin{align}
       \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(B^a_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]
       &=\mathbb{E}^Q\left[\frac{1}{1+\mathcal{E}(\tilde{B}^b_T+\rho T)}\right]\\\\
       &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{1+\exp(\rho T-T/2+T x)}dx=:A
\end{align}$$

Approach 2: Let $B^a_t=\rho B^b_t+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}B_t$ where $B_t$ is independent from $B^b$. Then
$$\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(B^a_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]
    &=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(\rho B^b_T+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}B_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]\\\\
    &=\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{E}(\sqrt{1-\rho^2}B_T)]\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(\rho B^b_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]\\\\
    &=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\mathcal{E}(\rho B^b_T)}{1+\mathcal{E}(B^b_T)}\right]\\\\
    &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\exp(-T\rho^2/2+T\rho x)f(x)}{1+\exp(-T/2+Tx)}dx=:B
\end{align}$$
However, the integrands in A and B do not equal. I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere.